# Работа с классом Vector на Java

Tags: java, алгоритм, коллекции, vector

Столкнулся с одной задачей, в которой дан вектор чисел. Необходимо выяснить сколько среди них различных и вывести на экран. 
Я подумал может быть есть возможность сделать это за один проход, используя Collections, но не нашел подходящего метода...

Comment: `HashSet` и не нужно никаких методов

Comment: Нужны методы HashSet)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!